# Regenerate thumbnails for images that are not in the media library

Tags: thumbnails

I have a wordpress site that has thousands of images in the uploads folder that are connected to posts in a custom post type. What would be a good way to regenerate these images to create new thumbnails?

Comment: The images were uploaded directly to the upload folders? I mean, without being registered in the DB?

Comment: There is a form on the front end, the images are cropped and renamed. They are in the uploads folder. There are custom fields that hold the urls to these images. Tons of images. I believe that is why they are not in the library because there are just so many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wp-content/uploads images wont regenerate if they are not shown in the Media Library because those media ID's needs to be there in the database.You need to first add your images on the media libray with the help of [add-from-server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/)
plugin.

Then with [regenerate-thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin you can then regenerate all of you images.

Hope that helps!!